# To select range of rows from SQL Server while joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select a range of records from my db while joining two tables.

My query to join the tables is

```
SELECT c.customernumber, 
       c.customername, 
       c.duedate, 
       c.chequenumber, 
       c.amount, 
       c.status, 
       n.nextdate, 
       a.tel, 
       a.tel2, 
       a.mobile 
FROM   currentcustemerchequetable c 
       INNER JOIN newtdate n 
               ON c.customernumber = n.customerno 
       INNER JOIN customeraddresstable a 
               ON c.customernumber = a.code
```

I need to select, say records between 10 and 25 from the result of the above query.

The above query returns thousand records, so I need only selected records from it

Comment: Provide some sample data and expect result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `OFFSET`

for example getting 20 rows after 10 rows;

```
Select 
    c.CustomerNumber,
    c.CustomerName,
    c.DueDate,
    c.ChequeNumber,
    c.Amount,
    c.Status,
    n.NextDate,
    a.tel,
    a.tel2,
    a.mobile 
from 
    currentCustemerChequeTable c 
    inner join NewTDate n on c.CustomerNumber = n.CustomerNO 
    inner join CustomerAddressTable a on c.CustomerNumber = a.code
ORDER BY c.CustomerNumber 
  OFFSET 10 ROWS
  FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also generate the sequence via `row_number()` function

```
with cte as 
(
     select *,
             row_number() over (order by CustomerNumber)  Seq
     from <query>
)

select * from cte
where seq >= 10 and seq <= 25
```

However, here is one advantage over `offset` is that you could also fetch records by `departmental` wise. So, the query would be

```
with cte as 
 (
     select *,
                 row_number() over (partition by <col> order by CustomerNumber)  Seq
     from <query>
)

select * from cte
where seq >= 10 and seq <= 25
```

Comment: bro what is cte in that customer cheque table? i dont follow